# Android,sensor orientation doesn't change

Tags: android, android-sensors

I have problem with my app and i have no idea where is the cause.
I am developing an application, which connect with PC by Wi-Fi, and shows on phone screen orientation. All about sending works perfectly, but part with orientation sensor not. The strange fact is when i do app only with sensor part it works. Maybe threads something changes.

in on create

```
        txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtView);
        txtView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtView2);
        txtView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtView3);
        SensorManager mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        Sensor mOrientation = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION);
```

in on sensor change

```
  @Override
  public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
      azimuth_angle = event.values[0];
      pitch_angle = event.values[1];
      roll_angle = event.values[2];
      txtView.setText(azimuth_angle+"  ");
      txtView2.setText(pitch_angle+"  ");
      txtView3.setText(roll_angle+"  ");
      Log.e("kacper", azimuth_angle+"  "+pitch_angle+"  "+roll_angle);
```

i checked that onSensorChanged is no called. why its not working when in new empty activity works good and refresh very often.

Comment: are your sure that your device have ORIENTATION sensor

Comment: i am sure because app builded of 3 textviews works. iam trying add this functionality to my app and onSensorChanged never called

Comment: are you implements SensorEventListener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you register the listener?

```
    mSensormanager.registerListener(this, mOrientation ,
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
```